# Semiconductor Laser

Tags: semiconductor-physics, laser

If a semiconductor laser is operated in a DC condition, the injected current is
higher than the threshold, that is to say, the gain will be larger than the overall
cavity loss. So, the stimulated emission will be built up to dominate the photon
density of cavity. Is it correct that photon will be generated unlimitedly to get high
output power?

Comment: Why will the output become unlimited? You only have a certain inversion and certain cavity characteristics.

Comment: Energy conservation makes that impossible. The total power output can never exceed the total power input. Can you destroy such a laser in a very short amount of time by increasing the current too much? Yes. That's why they are either being fed by a constant current source or being operated with an optical feedback to limit the power to a level that is safe for the device.

Answer (score 0):

Every laser has a loss associated with it. So, what matters most is the round-trip gain and the round-trip loss.  Part of the loss is the output coupling of the cavity.  Even in the case where there is 0 (zero) output coupling (so the cavity mirrors are 100% reflecting) there will not be an infinite build up of photons due to the fact that there is loss and the gain will saturate to meet this loss.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

> the gain will be larger than the overall cavity loss.

This is not correct.

When the pump power exceeds the threshold, the gain stops increasing. Rather than increasing the gain, increasing pump power only increases the emitted power.

We sometimes describe this by saying the gain is *pinned* at the threshold level.

There are techniques like *Q switching* where the cavity loss is deliberately increased to allow the gain to be increased, and then when the cavity is restored to its low-loss configuration we have for a moment a situation with gain higher than the loss. This is used to produce a strong output pulse before the cavity re-equilibrates with the gain equal to the cavity loss.

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: What you're referring to is gain saturation.